# I am trying to get text from an HTML file, but I dont know how(googled but idk where to look)

Tags: python, html

First of all, I am kinda new to python so my question may be dumb.

I am trying to get text from an html file on my pc, 
and a google search gives me confusing things that I dont understand.

I want to look in the file for the string "ONLINE:" and I want python to 
give me the names seperated from commas after it, like that:

Input:

ONLINE: User1, User2, User3

Output:

User_1 = "User1" User_2 = "User2" User_3 = "User3"

Is there a way to do this like it is possible to do this 
with .txt files?

I made this account just for that question and I am not good at english so dont comment on my language

Answer (score 0):

This works for the specific input you gave as example

```
with open('path/to/file', 'r') as file:
    file_text = file.read()
    list_users = file_text.split("ONLINE: ", 1)[1].split(', ')
```

You open the file and separate every user into a list.
Now you can do whatever you want with the names.

For example if you want to print:

```
for user in list_users:
    print(user)
```

Comment: first of all, thx for your help, I rly apreciate it.

I tried what you suggested, and the output was this:

https://file.io/J7zaF5jJ

I thought you may want some backround. So the file is an automatic chatlog from a game, and I want to do something with an api and the player names. If it helps, here is the file I wanna get the names from:

https://file.io/XkciUkjQ

Comment: Output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dq_AqbrtbgN__HxD_070F9nGFh7FnDWa/view?usp=sharing

original File:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dq_AqbrtbgN__HxD_070F9nGFh7FnDWa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show only the part where users are online? because i looked for the word 'online' and it did not found it

Comment: ok is there a way to send files to you? I cant do it with google drive cuz it isnt rly displaying html files right. maybee an email? idk